# Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated

Tags: php

> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\user\adodb\adodb-xmlschema.inc.php on
>   line 385

```
$this->data =& new dbData( $this, $attributes );
```

Comment: Please rephrase as a question.

Comment: Yes? And so...?  After you return the new object, you can use references on it then - but there's no returning the object reference in the constructor.

Comment: You can't return that by reference because it has not been assigned to anything yet. Once its in a variable somewhere you can then pass its reference.

Answer (score 5):

```
$this->data =& new dbData( $this, $attributes );
```

This is old PHP4-style code to prevent object copies when you assign it to another variable. With PHP5 that has been improved and you can simply use:

```
$this->data = new dbData( $this, $attributes );
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the line so it reads `$this->data = new dbData( $this, $attributes );`